# How can I pass every key to check if something is in it - Python

Tags: python

I'm new with Python and I need some help with the dictionary function.

I have a text file of actor and movies, it look like this:

```
Brad Pitt, Sleepers, Troy, Meet Joe Black, Oceans Eleven, Seven, Mr & Mrs Smith
Tom Hanks, You have got mail, Apollo 13, Sleepless in Seattle, Catch Me If You Can
Meg Ryan, You have got mail, Sleepless in Seattle
Diane Kruger, Troy, National Treasure
Dustin Hoffman, Sleepers, The Lost City
...
```

The dictionary order is in sets, the movies are the keys and the actors are the values.

My input is an actor name and I want to check in the movies he played for who is the co-actors who played with.. how can I check this?

I try something like:

```
actor = raw_input().lower()
coList = movieDict.keys()
coSet = set()
for keys in range(len(coList)):
    for i in coList:
        if actor == i:
            continue
        else:
            coSet.add(actor)
print (', '.join(coSet()))
```

But it doesn't work..

The output need to seems like:

```
Brad Pitt
The actor's co-stars are:
Angelina Jolie, Anthony Hopkins, Diane Kruger, Dustin Hoffman, George Clooney, Julia Roberts, Kevin Bacon,
Morgan Freeman
```

Comment: "The dictionary order in sets" -- I can't make sense out of that clause. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Can you please post the rest of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do. Look through a dictionary of `{movie: set(actors)}` and you want all the co-actors of an actor. I'm assuming the `movieDict` has already been constructed.

Not sure I understand what your outer loop is intended to do `for keys in range(len(coList)):` seems completely redundant.

Simplifying:

```
actor = input().lower()   # raw_input() in Py2
coSet = set()
for movie, actors in movieDict.items():
    if actor in actors:
        coSet |= actors
print(', '.join(coSet))
```

This `coSet` will include the original `actor` but can be simply `remove`d if necessary.

Comment: Exactly what i need, the raw_input is because of the string, doesn't work without this. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for actors and see the movies they've been in, it seems that maybe a better approach would be to make the actors the keys and the movies their values. That is, I search

```
"Brad Pitt"
```

and get back his values a.k.a. movies

```
"Sleepers, Troy, Meet Joe Black, Oceans Eleven, Seven, Mr & Mrs Smith"
```

Assuming that your input file looks similar to the excerpt posted and you have the pattern

```
'ACTOR', 'movie1', 'movie2', etc...
```

You can go through the file line by line and treating each line like a list where the first index of the list, line[0] is the Actor/Key. Everything else in the line gets passed in as a single list to be the value of that key.

Then you can also search specific values and have them return keys to find the co-stars.

I think this is what you're trying to do. Is this a correct understanding? I'd be happy to post code as a starting point if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As your database gets larger you are going to want to avoid iterating over every movie ever, hoping to find the actor you're interested in.

I would create an extra `dict` in which you can look up actors as well as the one in which you look up movies.  So `filmography['Brad Pitt']` gives you a list of his movies and `cast['Sleepers']` gives you a list of that movie's actors.  Here's how it could be done:

```
# The set-up:

filmography = {}
cast = {}
with open(filename, 'rt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: continue
        cells = line.split(',')
        actor = cells[0].strip()
        movies = [movie.strip() for movie in cells[1:]]
        filmography.setdefault(actor,[]).extend(movies)
        for movie in movies:
            cast.setdefault(movie,[]).append(actor)

# The look-up:

def CoStars(actor):
    return {costar for movie in filmography[actor] for costar in cast[movie] if costar is not actor}

# The test:

for actor in filmography:
    print(actor + ' -> ' + ', '.join(CoStars(actor)))
```

Prints:

```
Brad Pitt -> Dustin Hoffman, Diane Kruger
Tom Hanks -> Meg Ryan
Meg Ryan -> Tom Hanks
Dustin Hoffman -> Brad Pitt
Diane Kruger -> Brad Pitt
```

Answer (score 0):

This will find all of the movies the actor has been in and put that in the movies set and then iterate through that set of movies and create a set of actors in those moves. This set of actors represents every actor the given actor costared with. At the end the original actor is removed from the set of costars.

```
actor = raw_input().lower()
movies = set()
costars = set()
for key, value in movieDict.items():
  if actor in value:
    movies = movies.union(set([key]))

for movie in movies:
    costars = costars.union(movieDict[movie])

costars = costars.difference(set([actor]))
```